# Android OpenGL performance issue

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es

Hi 
I have been using open gl to draw objects on a blank black background and the performance has been fine so far. Now when I add a rectangular texture(similar to a level background) peformance is poor. How can I improve this?

The code I use to draw the background is as follows and is implemented in the onDraw() method

```
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
level1.draw(gl);
gl.glPopMatrix();
```

The texture for this background is loaded once as it does not change or animate.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `sleep(100000)` from `draw()`.

Comment: Are you sure sleep() is related to slowdown :)

Comment: I dont have a sleep(100000) in my draw method. Is it possible to modify the objects draw method so that it is not called on every onDraw but rather before this and kept in place?

Answer (score 0):

You say you are using a rectangular texture. Have you made sure its dimensions are a power of 2? Depending on the implementation of OpenGL it can either work fine, work slowly or not work at all if you don't.